# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php

Here code. Please help me!!! Thanks very much

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

```html
public function update($table, $data, $cond){
  $updateKeys = NULL;
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $updateKeys .= "$key=:$key";
  }
  $updateKeys = rtrim($updateKeys, ",");

  $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $updateKeys WHERE $cond";
  $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value);
  }
  return $stmt->execute();

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put "," in  `$updateKeys .= "$key=:$key,";`.Please use

```
function update($table, $data, $cond){
        $updateKeys = NULL;
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $updateKeys .= "$key=:$key,";
        }

        $updateKeys = rtrim($updateKeys, ",");

        echo $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $updateKeys WHERE $cond";
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $value);
        }
        return $stmt->execute();

    }
```

Comment: because of , was not there , there was mismatch of  parameter

Comment: If u feel that answer is correct check the right mark